# Optimize/ Move transitionTo in common place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I use the below code in a mixin. Is it possible to paramterize & implement the transition to code in a method, so that I do not have to write it multiple times;

```
var routeName = 'some.nested.route';
var someCode = 'XYZ';
if (this.get('targetObject')) {
    // This is when coming from component
    this.get('targetObject').transitionToRoute(routeName, someCode ).then(function(newRoute) {
        newRoute.controller.set('booleanVar', false);
    });
} else {
    if (typeof this.transitionToRoute == 'function') {
        // This is when coming from controller
        this.transitionToRoute(routeName, someCode ).then(function(newRoute) {
            newRoute.controller.set('booleanVar', false);
        });
    } else {
        // This is when coming from route
        this.transitionTo(routeName, someCode ).then(function(newRoute) {
            newRoute.controller.set('booleanVar', false);
        });
    }                                   
}
```

Say I can pass just routeName & someCode to that method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
transitionExec = function() {
return this.transitionToRoute(routeName, someCode ).then(function(newRoute) {
        newRoute.controller.set('booleanVar', false);
    });
}
this.get('targetObject').transitionExec();
```

Comment: Actually I want to have the method with parameterized routeName & someCode

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is highly dynamic so just create a new variable with your function. Don't forget to `.bind(this)` or call it with `.call(this, arg1, arg2, ...)` or you will lose your `this`-context:

```
let transition = typeof this.transitionToRoute == 'function' ? this.transitionToRoute.bind(this) : this.transitionTo.bind(this);

transition(routeName, someCode).then(newRoute => {
  ...
});
```